# Call generic method and pass generic delegate parameter using Type set at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, types, delegates

**EDIT**: This is a Unity 2018.4 project, which uses a custom version of Mono. Scripting runtime version is ".NET 4.x Equivalent" and API compatibility level is ".NET Standard 2.0"

---

I have a custom event system using generics with `AddListener<T>` and `RemoveListener<T>` methods that accept a `EventDelegate<T>` parameter. Elsewhere in code, given a `Type` determined at runtime, I'd like to add and remove listeners using a delegate of the appropriate type and simply know when the event was raised. I don't need to know of any payload that comes with the event.

It may be worth nothing that `<T>` is always derived from a specific abstract base type.

In the following examples, I have a static generic method on a static class that takes a generic delegate as a parameter. I'm trying to invoke the generic method using `Type` at runtime and I'd like to pass the generic delegate of `Type` as a parameter. Is this possible without having an established method with the proper signature at compile time?

Static class with generic delegate and generic method that accepts the delegate as a parameter:

```
public static class GameEvent
{
   public delegate void EventDelegate<in T>(T e) where T : BaseEvent;

   public static void AddListener<T>(EventDelegate<T> listener) where T : BaseEvent
   {
      ...
   }

   public abstract class BaseEvent : EventArgs
   {
   }
}
```

`Type` will always be derived from a specific base type.

Example derived class:

```
public class CustomGameEvent : GameEvent.BaseEvent
{
   public CustomGameEvent(object a, object b) // Constructor has 0 or more parameters of unknown type.
   {
   }
}
```

The above setup works well, and I have numerous custom events that are functioning.

For example, in some class method, I would add a listener and implement a delegate method for receiving the event,

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
   GameEvent.AddListener<CustomGameEvent>(this.CustomGameEventHandler);
}

private void CustomGameEventHandler(CustomGameEvent e)
{
   ... // This works and I can access properties of `e`.
}
```

Now onto my issue.

Elsewhere, I would like to call `GameEvent.AddListner<T>` using a `Type` determined at runtime, where `Type` is derived from `GameEvent.BaseEvent`, however I'm not sure what to pass as a parameter when invoking the method. That's where I'm stuck.

I setup a method that receives a `GameEvent.BaseEvent` parameter instead of the derived `Type`. Does it even make sense to have a method that accepts the base type when I'd like the delegate method to accept the derived type?

```
private Type type = typeof(CustomGameEvent); // Some type that inherits from BaseEvent.

private void GameEventHandler(GameEvent.BaseEvent e)
{
   // Do something here. Don't care that e is the base type.
   // I just want to know when the `Type` event was raised.
   // Accept any parameter that is derived from GameEvent.BaseEvent.
}

private void AddListener()
{
   var mi = typeof(GameEvent).GetMethod(nameof(GameEvent.AddListener));
   // -> void AddListener[T](EventDelegate`1)

   var miGeneric = mi?.MakeGenericMethod(type);
   // -> void AddListener[CustomGameEvent](EventDelegate`1)

   var delegateType = typeof(GameEvent.EventDelegate<>).MakeGenericType(type);
   // -> GameEvent+EventDelegate`1[CustomGameEvent]

   var parameters = new object[] { (GameEvent.EventDelegate<GameEvent.BaseEvent>)this.GameEventHandler };
   miGeneric?.Invoke(null, parameters);
   // -> When "AddListener<CustomGameEvent>()" is invoked, it receives a 
   //    "GameEvent+EventDelegate`1[GameEvent+BaseEvent]" not a
   //    "GameEvent+EventDelegate`1[CustomGameEvent]"
}
```

This works for the most part and does what I'd expect, because I'm explicitly casting the `this.GameEventHandler` to `(GameEvent.EventDelegate<GameEvent.BaseEvent>)` and passing that as a parameter. But I'd like to cast the parameter object to the type stored in `delegateType`, so that `AddListener<CustomGameEvent>()` actually receives an `EventDelegate<CustomGameEvent>` and not a `EventDelegate<GameEvent.BaseEvent>`. Is that possible, and if so, how?

Can `GameEventHandler(GameEvent.BaseEvent e)` even be used as the delegate method if the object was cast to `EventDelegate<CustomGameEvent>` or would the invoke fail due to the signature mismatch?

I've tried using `Convert.ChangeType()`, however that fails with `InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.`.

```
   var parameters = new object[]
      {
         Convert.ChangeType(
            (GameEvent.EventDelegate<GameEvent.BaseEvent>)this.GameEventHandler,
            delegateType)
      };
```

I also tried using a generic static helper method `CastInto<T>(object obj)`, but that didn't cast as I hoped it would.

```
private void AddListener()
{
   ... // delegateType is stored

   var miCastInto = this.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(CastInto)).MakeGenericMethod(delegateType);
   // -> EventDelegate`1 CastInto[EventDelegate`1](System.Object), but is that what
   //    I want? Should it be:  EventDelegate`1[CustomGameEvent]
   //       CastInto[EventDelegate`1[CustomGameEvent]](System.Object)

   object o1 = (GameEvent.EventDelegate<GameEvent.BaseEvent>)this.GameEventHandler;
   // -> GameEvent.EventDelegate<GameEvent.BaseEvent> ... as expected.

   object o2 = miCastInto.Invoke(null, new[] { o });
   // -> GameEvent.EventDelegate<GameEvent.BaseEvent> ... not <CustomGameEvent>.

   var parameters = new object[] { castedObject }; // <- Wrong parameter type.

   ...
}

public static T CastInto<T>(object obj)
{
   return (T)obj;
}
```

I'm not even sure if I should be trying to finesse the `GameEventHandler(GameEvent.BaseEvent e)` delegate to `typeDelegate`. If it can be converted would `GameEventHandler(GameEvent.BaseEvent e)` still be called when the event was raised?

I saw `Delegate.CreateDelegate()`, but I don't really understand if that should be used here or how it should be used.

Whatever delegate is established, it would also be used with a similar `GameEvent.RemoveListener<T>` call at a later time (using the same `Type`), so the delegate probably has to be stored with the class instance and not re-created when used later. I'm assuming the second delegate creation would be seen as distinct (not the same reference to the original creation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to create a delegate of a specific `Type` object.

```
var delegateType = typeof(GameEvent.EventDelegate<>).MakeGenericType(type);
// -> GameEvent+EventDelegate`1[CustomGameEvent]

var methodInfo = typeof(YourClass).GetMethod(
    "GameEventHandler", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

var parameters = new object[] { 
    Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, this, methodInfo) 
};
```

The [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.createdelegate?view=net-5.0#System_Delegate_CreateDelegate_System_Type_System_Object_System_Reflection_MethodInfo_) that you are calling here creates a delegate that calls an instance method. The second parameter indicates the instance on which you want the method to be called.

Comment: I receive an `ArgumentException: Couldn't bind to method 'GameEventHandler'`. when creating the delegate. I might have tried that earlier when I was investigating `Delegate.CreateDelegate()`, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

If I add a `void GameEventHandler(CustomGameEvent e)` method overload to the class, it does work, but not when just trying to use the base event type as the method parameter `void GameEventHandler(GameEvent.BaseEvent e)`.

Comment: @MichaelRyan Huh, it seems like variance is only taken into account when you call it with a method info. Now that I think about it, this does make sense. See the edit.

Comment: Ah! It never occurred to me to try the overload that takes the MethodInfo. That works great. Thanks!

Comment: I see now that the MS docs explicitly state that this overload  allows for variance: "Demonstrate contravariance of parameter types and covariance of return types by using the delegate Example to represent MyMethod. The delegate binds to the method because the parameter of the delegate is more restrictive than the parameter of the method (that is, the delegate accepts an instance of Derived, which can always be safely passed to a parameter of type Base)" -- This is great to know -- Thanks again!

Comment: @MichaelRyan Yeah, I knew that was a thing, so I thought it would work with the string overload too... But now thinking about it, if this were allowed, this would introduce a lot of complexities to `CreateDelegate`, and that's probably why they didn't implement it.